# Пошаговая отладка VS2019 пропускает итерации цикла

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++, отладка, visual-studio-2019

Создал простой код с циклом на Visual Studio 2019:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int x = 10;
    while (x > 5)
    {
        cout << "something";
        x -= 1;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Для демонстрации изменения счётчика в ходе итераций цикла запустил пошаговую отладку нажатием F10 и далее передвигаюсь по строкам кода этой же клавишей. Указатель текущей строки дошёл до первой строки тела цикла, а потом **просто перескочил к `return 0`**, установив значения переменных так, будто цикл уже выполнился. За предыдущими версиями VS такого не замечалось.

Вопрос: как выполнить каждую итерацию цикла по шагам без пропусков,  подобных описанному?

P.S. F9 не помогает, заходит в саму инструкцию, как, собственно, и должно быть.

Comment: Нажать F1 и прочитать справку.

Comment: Там есть что-то про F11

Comment: @AlexeyTen, F11 это шаг с выходом, я знаю. Возможно, недостаточно понятно описал в вопросе, я перехожу к следующей строке нажатием F10 и он всё равно доходит до первой инструкции цикла и сразу перескакивает в конец программы. F1 ведёт к справке по другой теме.

Comment: У меня в Debug версии все работает, а в Release нет. Собираешь Debug?

Comment: @NotBjarneStroustrup, Спасибо огромное! Действительно совсем забыл, что сменил вариант сборки на release. Вынесите это в ответ, пожалуйста.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Возможно вы собрали в Release версию. Соберите в Debug.